# Add elements to to isotope container makes images overlap

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have implemented jquery isotope on my image gallery.
In gallery I have image upload form, after user upload image I return Json object with data about uploaded image.
Based on that data I want to add new image to isotope container.
I have tried a few ways but all fail.
The last one add image to container but new image is bellow the old image.
I must be missing something but can't find what.
[image]

```
$("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxForm({
...
success: function (result) {
                var $container = $('#container');
                var $newItems = $('<div class="imgItem"><a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" href="' + @Url.Content("~/") + result.messageOriginal+ '"> <img src="'+ result.message +'" /> </div></a>');

                $container.prepend($newItems).isotope('reloadItems').isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });
...
```

This is how I load items when user open page

```
$(window).load(function () {
        var $container = $('#container');

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.imgItem',
            filter: '*',

            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
...
```

And this is template for each item:

```
<div class="imgItem">
                <a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" 
           href="@Url.Content("~/" + @i.Media.PathOriginal)" 
           >
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/" + @i.Media.PathMedium)" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: When you append (add) new items to Isotope's container, Isotope needs the item's widths and heights to lay them out properly. See the imagesLoaded option and how to load and append new items with Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. So I wrapped it with its image loading plugin as follows

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $('#container').isotope({
          // options
          sortBy : 'random',
          layoutMode: 'masonry',
          itemSelector : '.imgItem'
        });
    });
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
var $newItems = $('<div class="imgItem" style="float:left;"><a class="fancybox-button"....
```